# Run scripts when "running" on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant, compilation

Eclipse has that green arrow button we use to compile and execute projects.

I wanted to run extra scripts on it, like build a new jar file, or deploy a war file in an external Tomcat instance, delete the folder related to that war and restart Tomcat, or update a jar dependancy before compiling, or even deleting a property file so that it's not included on created jar.

I suppose Ant is able to do these stuff, but how I can attach before and after scripts to Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse is nicelly integrated with Ant. Just put your `build.xml` in your project, right click on it, select "Run as" and then "Ant Build".

Then the IDE will execute your script and sent the Output to the Console Tab. I'm currently using it to deploy applications to an external WebSphere Portal Server and it works smoothly.

Comment: Thanks gonna give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

Just execute an ant script doing this, use the black ant button instead of the green run button.

Comment: Where's this black ant button? I can't find it

Comment: It is the one looking like a spider. Once you linked your ant script in the settings you should be ready to go. Mouseover messages will help you finding it.

Comment: BTW: If you have your buildscript already created, why not use Continuous Integration anyway? Jenkins is 'horribly' easy to install and set up. I am talking about locally!. I did not need any tutorials and it took me like 2 hours with no prior education on any of the available CI servers. Biggest hurdle was to try and me thinking it would be too complex for me to get it to work.